# SelectSingleNode returns null after saving XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

Hello so I have a `GetterSetter.cs` with this code

```
public Uri ShowImdb { get; set; }
```

and It gets info from IMDB link for what show name user typed (e.g game of thrones it gives game of thrones imdb link to that ShowImdb) and then I write that info to an `XML` file for saving-reading purposes with this code,

```
GetterSetter i = new GetterSetter();
XmlNode xImdb = xDoc.CreateElement("ShowImdb");
xImdb.InnerText = i.ShowImdb.ToString();
```

and I wanna read it when user open the program with this code,

```
private ObservableCollection<GetterSetter> _getterSetter = new ObservableCollection<GetterSetter>();

public ObservableCollection<GetterSetter> showList
    {
        get { return this._getterSetter; }
    }

XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("Shows"); 
foreach (GetterSetter i in showList)
{
    i.ShowImdb = xNode.SelectSingleNode("ShowImdb").InnerText;
}
```

it doesnt work and I tried this as well,

```
xNode.SelectSingleNode("ShowImdb").InnerText = i.ShowImdb.ToString();
```

this time it gives me error which is,

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ShowTrack.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have also readed the `NullReferenceException` question but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all  `xNode.SelectSingleNode("ShowImdb")` doesn't exist in your doc which is causing `NullReferenceException`.

If you want to persist changes to *xDucument* you'll have to save it before closing your application (releasing *XDocument* object). Use [XDocument.Save(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830(v=vs.110).aspx) for it.

---

**UPDATE**:

Also remember that `SelectSingleNode(XPath)` takes as a parameter XPath but not elements name and works on current context.

> Selects the first XmlNode that matches the XPath expression. Any prefixes found in the XPath expression are resolved using the supplied XmlNamespaceManager.

You're using exact name `XPath` pattern which will return single element **within the current context** by specified name.

Now while adding element you do this on `XDocument` level but then trying to read particular element from underlying *Show* element. So **contexts are different** as there is no *ShowImdb*.

Long story short, you're creating *ShowImdb* on root level and then trying to read it from one of the nested *Show*-nodes  but it doesn't exist there. Result - `NullReferenceException`.